# Splitting into array with conditions from the string in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split

```
String numbers = "0020020074#223#522620#1#9#0:0024202968#223#522620#1#59#0:0024039694#223#522620#1#1282#0:0024378742#223#522620#2#51#0"
```

Please i am new to java, i have tried to split this based on conditions.

I have successfully splited them after every column(:). but i need to get only the first 10 digits based on the number after the third #.

I mean, if the number after the 3rd # is 1, it should display the first 10 digits before the first #

If the number is 2, dis play the first 10 digits too.

The 1 or 2 explains the currency in the account, so i want to display all the account with 1 in the same combo box, then all the accounts with 2 in the same combo box. (the first 10 digits is the account number).

instead of displaying all of them.

Kindly help me with this, i will be delivering my mini banking application using java by tomorrow.

Comment: Use `String`s to store your account numbers.

Comment: What about split for #, read the number and save it in numerAfterTheSpecial and read split[numerAfterTheSpecial - 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbers = "0020020074#223#522620#1#9#0:" +
                     "0024202968#223#522620#1#59#0:" +
                     "0024039694#226#522620#3#1282#0:" +
                     "0024378742#223#522620#2#51#0";

    String[] nums = numbers.split(":");

    int i = 0;
    while(i < nums.length){

        if(nums[i].split("#")[3].charAt(0) == '1')
            System.out.println(nums[i].split("#")[0]);
        else if(nums[i].split("#")[3].charAt(0) == '2')
            System.out.println(nums[i].split("#")[0]);
        else
            System.out.println(nums[i].split("#")[1]);

        i++;
    }

}
```